# Delete children after parent is deleted in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My problem is the following:

I have the two models `Entry` and `Tag` linked by a many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy. Now I want to delete every `Tag` that doesn't have any corresponding `Entry` after an `Entry` is deleted.

*Example to illustrate what I want:*

- `Entry 1` with tags `python`, `java`
- `Entry 2` with tags `python`, `c++`

With these two entries the database contains the tags `python`, `java`, and `c++`. If I now delete `Entry 2` I want SQLAlchemy to automatically delete the `c++` tag from the database. Is it possible to define this behavior in the `Entry` model itself or is there an even more elegant way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this question was asked awhile back here: [Setting delete-orphan on SQLAlchemy relationship causes AssertionError: This AttributeImpl is not configured to track parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234082/setting-delete-orphan-on-sqlalchemy-relationship-causes-assertionerror-this-att/9264556#9264556)

This is the "many-to-many orphan" problem.  jadkik94 is close in that you should use events to catch this, but I try to recommend against using the Session inside of mapper events, though it works in this case.

Below, I take the answer verbatim from the other SO question, and replace the word "Role" with "Entry":

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import attributes

Base= declarative_base()

tagging = Table('tagging',Base.metadata,
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True),
    Column('entry_id', Integer, ForeignKey('entry.id', ondelete='cascade'), primary_key=True)
)

class Tag(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entry'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_names = association_proxy('tags', 'name')

    tags = relationship('Tag',
                        secondary=tagging,
                        backref='entries')

@event.listens_for(Session, 'after_flush')
def delete_tag_orphans(session, ctx):
    # optional: look through Session state to see if we want
    # to emit a DELETE for orphan Tags
    flag = False

    for instance in session.dirty:
        if isinstance(instance, Entry) and \
            attributes.get_history(instance, 'tags').deleted:
            flag = True
            break
    for instance in session.deleted:
        if isinstance(instance, Entry):
            flag = True
            break

    # emit a DELETE for all orphan Tags.   This is safe to emit
    # regardless of "flag", if a less verbose approach is
    # desired.
    if flag:
        session.query(Tag).\
            filter(~Tag.entries.any()).\
            delete(synchronize_session=False)


e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

r1 = Entry()
r2 = Entry()
r3 = Entry()
t1, t2, t3, t4 = Tag("t1"), Tag("t2"), Tag("t3"), Tag("t4")

r1.tags.extend([t1, t2])
r2.tags.extend([t2, t3])
r3.tags.extend([t4])
s.add_all([r1, r2, r3])

assert s.query(Tag).count() == 4

r2.tags.remove(t2)

assert s.query(Tag).count() == 4

r1.tags.remove(t2)

assert s.query(Tag).count() == 3

r1.tags.remove(t1)

assert s.query(Tag).count() == 2
```

two almost identical SO questions qualifies this as something to have on hand so I've added it to the wiki at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/ManyToManyOrphan.

Comment: the only thing I notice here is that this code would perform the query on tags everytime a flush occurs, not only when a entry is deleted. but it solves the problem, thanks!

Comment: Well, sure you could also do a scan through session.deleted inside of after_flush() to see if any Entry objects have been deleted.  This may or may not add overhead that is more/less than that of the query. I'll add that in with a note.

Comment: there's another variant added on the wiki at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/ManyToManyOrphan too.

Answer (score 1):

I will let code speak for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, exc, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import func, Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

# Connection
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# Models
entry_tag_link = Table('entry_tag', Base.metadata,
    Column('entry_id', Integer, ForeignKey('entries.id')),
    Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)

class Entry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entries'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, default='')

    tags = relationship("Tag", secondary=entry_tag_link, backref="entries")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entry %s>' % (self.name,)

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag %s>' % (self.name,)

# Delete listener
def delete_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    print "---- DELETING %s ----" % (target,)
    print '-' * 20
    for t in target.tags:
        if len(t.entries) == 0:
            print ' ' * 5, t, 'is to be deleted'
            session.delete(t)
    print '-' * 20

event.listen(Entry, 'before_delete', delete_listener)

# Utility functions
def dump(session):
    entries = session.query(Entry).all()
    tags = session.query(Tag).all()

    print '*' * 20
    print 'Entries', entries
    print 'Tags', tags
    print '*' * 20


Base.metadata.create_all()

session = Session()

t1, t2, t3 = Tag(name='python'), Tag(name='java'), Tag(name='c++')

e1, e2 = Entry(name='Entry 1', tags=[t1, t2]), Entry(name='Entry 2', tags=[t1, t3])

session.add_all([e1,e2])
session.commit()

dump(session)

raw_input("---- Press return to delete the second entry and see the result ----")

session.delete(e2)
session.commit()

dump(session)
```

This code above uses the [after_delete event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_delete) of the SQLAlchemy ORM events. This line does the magic:

```
event.listen(Entry, 'before_delete', delete_listener)
```

This says to listen to all deletes to an `Entry` item, and call our listener which will do what we want. However, the docs do not recommend changing the session inside the events (see the warning in the link I added). But as far as I can see, it works, so it's up to you to see if this works for you.

Comment: there's a flaw in this example, which is that calling session.delete() inside of a mapper-level flush event won't necessarily take place within that flush, as the flush plan has already been determined at this point.

Comment: however, it does seem to work in this case, which is a bit curious to me.  I'd of course like the session to be fully usable in mapper flush events but there's a lot of reasons it can't do that right now.

Comment: yeah, it works due to some implementation details, that are not necessarily carved in stone.   For example, if you said session.delete() against some other class that didn't have a relationship to the parent, the deletes may or may not happen, depending on if other objects of that type were already set for deletion.

Comment: @zzzeek I read the warning but thought I should try it and see whatvwould happen... I thought it worked because I was deleting the tag in the **before**_delete event; maybe that plan was not made yet. Turns out it is just luck :)