# Cascade delete-orphan with Generic Associations (multiple parents) in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an sqlalchemy entity with two foreign keys because it can have one of two entirely different parents. Let's use *Address*, *Customer* and *Supplier* for the purpose of illustration. An *Address* can belong to either a *Customer* or a *Supplier* (and can have children in my case).

I want an address and its children to auto-delete as soon as it has zero parents, i.e. neither a *Customer* nor a *Supplier* refers to it.

I initially implemented this as

```
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customers.id')
    supplier_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('suppliers.id')
    # etc ...
```

According to sqlalchemy docs, the canonical way to implement [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html) is by either using *table-per-related* or *table-per-association*. Both of these don't seem to address the problem of delete cascades though:

- table-per-related: Since *Address* has children of its own, I would have to replicate the entire hierarchy below address per related. Otherwise the problem just moves to the children of *Address*
- table-per-association: with back references installed on *Address* this seems to be the same as my initial implementation, except now the immediate parents are rows in the association table. I don't see how `delete-orphan` would work here.

What is the correct way to handle `delete-orphan` cascades with Generic Associations in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. There are a couple of [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653824/delete-children-after-parent-is-deleted-in-sqlalchemy/12731232) [questions](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/listeners.html#many-to-many-orphan-deletion) on SO where people had this problem with many-to-many relations (essentially what table-per-association is). There's also an SQLAlchemy [Wiki](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/ManyToManyOrphan) entry that describes how to solve the problem.

The solution is to basically do `delete-orphan` manually by implementing an event listener that cleans up after each flush:

```
@event.listens_for(Session, 'after_flush')
def delete_address_orphans(session, ctx):
    if any(isinstance(i, Address) for i in session.dirty):
        query = session.query(Address).\
                filter_by(customer=None, supplier=None)
        orphans = query.all()
        for orphan in orphans:
            session.delete(orphan)
```

Note, that in my case I load the orphans first instead of simply adding `.delete()` to the query statement. This is because the latter would bypass cascades on the Address entity and thus not delete the children of Address.