# Automatic delete a sub-object when it is not longer referenced by any parent in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, object-oriented-database

There is a many-to-many-relationship between `A` and `B`.

```
a_b_relation= sa.Table('a_b_relation', _Base.metadata,
    sa.Column('a_oid', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('A.oid')),
    sa.Column('b_oid', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('B.oid'))
)


class A(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'A'

    _oid = sa.Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _bbb = sao.relationship('B', secondary=a_b_relation)


class B(_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'B'

    _oid = sa.Column('oid', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

An instance of `B` can be referenced by many `A` instances.
But when there there is no reference anymore `B` should be deleted automaticly.
The point is that the `A` instances are not deleted! They just modify there relationship to another instance of `B`.

Is there a SQLAlchemy way to do that? Or do I have to check that by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has a `delete-orphan` cascade that you can read about [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/cascades.html#delete-orphan). However, it does not work for many to many relationships since it requires that objects have "single parents":

> delete-orphan cascade implies that each child object can only have one parent at a time, so is configured in the vast majority of cases on a one-to-many relationship. Setting it on a many-to-one or many-to-many relationship is more awkward; for this use case, SQLAlchemy requires that the relationship() be configured with the single_parent argument, establishes Python-side validation that ensures the object is associated with only one parent at a time.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234082/setting-delete-orphan-on-sqlalchemy-relationship-causes-assertionerror-this-att) discusses a similar situation as yours.

Comment: I see. So the answer would be I have to handle it by myself because there is no SQLA or SQL-mechanism that do the job implicite. But using SQLA-event-handlers (like in the other question you linked) could help with that.

Comment: What do you think about using reference-counters to let the instance/row know that it is not longer referenced?