# how to delete many to many orphan childs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have two tables linked with an association table (many-to-many).
Goal: if I delete the parent all children without an entry in the association table should be deleted.

If I understood the documentation on https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#deleting-rows-from-the-many-to-many-table
this should work out of the box?
I also played with cascade="delete", however this delete too much

```
parentChildLinkTable = db.Table('plasGp',
    Column('parent_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('parents.id')),
    Column('gp_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('children.id'))
    )

class Child(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = "children"
    name = Column(db.String(250), nullable = False)
    parents = db.relationship("Parent",
        secondary = parentChildLinkTable,
        back_populates = "children")

class Parent(SurrogatePK, Model):
    __tablename__ = "parents"
    name= Column(db.String(50))
    children = db.relationship("Child",
        secondary = parentChildLinkTable,
        back_populates = "parents",
        cascade="delete")
```

To wrap up:
How to delete all children that are only mapped to the parent I want to delete.

Say

```
ParA -> ChildA
ParA -> ChildB
ParB -> ChildA
ParB -> ChildC
```

I delete ParB, then the result should be:

```
ParA -> ChildA
ParA -> ChildB
```

Comment: Deleting a parent from the session will only result in that parent's related rows being removed from the association table. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. For example, the `back_populates` parameters don't match up to the relevant attribute name on the opposite class.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264556/6560549 and https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/ManyToManyOrphan

Comment: Right at the bottom of that wiki link it points to [this many-to-many-orphan-deletion function](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/listeners.html#many-to-many-orphan-deletion) in the sqlalchemy-utils library.

Comment: Hi,Indeed the backpopulates were not correct.
auto_delete_orphans seem to do the trick. Thanks A lot!