# One sided cascade delete when dereferenced in a many-to-many secondary table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship. A user owns `Posts` and associates `Tags` with those posts.

I want the asymmetric configuration where `Posts` are only ever deleted explicitly, but `Tags` can be automatically cascade deleted whenever the simply do not apply to  any `Posts`. This might occur in one of two cases:

1) A `Post` is deleted which is the only one left with that specific `Tag`. The secondary table is auto cascaded and there are no rows with that `Tag`'s id in it, but currently that `Tag` remains in its own table. I want it to be automatically deleted.

2) A `Tag` is removed from the association with a `Post` such that the same situation as above is rendered. The `Tag` should be auto deleted then also.

```
second_table = Table('second_table', db.Model.metadata,
    Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    posts = db.relationship("Post", secondary=second_table, back_populates='tags')

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   tags = db.relationship("Tag", secondary=second_table, back_populates='posts')
```

In its current form the relationship is completely symmetric and when items are removed from the secondary table they both persist in either the `Post` or `Tag` tables.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264556/6560549? Idea is to use an `after_flush` event to issue a bulk query that would 'clean up' any `Tags` that didn't have associations.

Comment: @SuperShoot thanks that did the trick - was what I expected but didnt instinctively know how to do it (and optimally).